# Applying a function to every cell of dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm a bit confused on how to carry out a computation over dataframes.
Basically I have 10 dataframes of let's say 10rows and 10columns.
I'd like to basically iterate through a certain cell in every dataframe, append them into a list and apply a function on it.

Example:
Get all df(0,0) from the 10 dataframes and append them into a list. Eventually apply a normalisation function to them and populate their normalised scores back to their respective dataframes.

Below is the kind of calculation I want to do once I've retrieved all of the df(0,0) cells from the 10 different dataframes (eg. rangex being the list)

```
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)),
...                    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)),
...                    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)),
...                    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)),
...                    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])


rangex = [df1.iloc[0,0], df2.iloc[0,0], df3.iloc[0,0], df4.iloc[0,0]]

OldRange = (3.0 - (-3.0))  
NewRange = (100.0 - 0.0) 
listrangex=[]
for elem in rangex:
    val = (elem - np.mean(rangex))/np.std(rangex)
    val = (((val - (-3.0)) * NewRange) / OldRange) + 0.0
    listrangex.append( val )
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I imagine stacks each dataframe to a columns, join them, compute the normalization and assign back.

Comment: I've edited my code to make it more understandable I hope

Comment: There's an XY problem here.  Making the list is easy `[d.at[0, 0] for d in list_of_dfs]`.  Assign back is easy(ish) `list_of_dfs[0].loc[:] = list_of_dfs[0] * 3`.  However, there is likely a better way to do this all at once if we knew what your plan was.

Comment: Is there a very efficient way of assigning a function to all specific cells in a dataframe (knowing that all dataframes are the same)?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC: All at once(sorta)

#### Setup

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])

dict_of_dfs = {f'df{i}': pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(25).reshape(5, 5)) for i in range(10)}

OldRange = np.array([-3, 3])
NewRange = np.array([0, 100])
```

If you have a list of dataframes, the easy way to get a dictionary is

```
dict_of_dfs = dict(enumerate(list_of_dfs))
```

---

#### Calculate Moments

```
df = pd.concat(dict_of_dfs)

mu = df.mean(level=1)
sg = df.std(level=1)
```

#### Define Normalization

```
def nrm(d):
    _d = (d - mu) / sg
    o = OldRange[1] - OldRange[0]
    n = NewRange[1] - NewRange[0]
    return (_d - OldRange[0]) * o / n + NewRange[0]
```

#### Update DataFrames with normalized data

```
for k, d in dict_of_dfs.items():
    d.loc[:] = nrm(d)
```

#### Produce a new DataFrame via `groupby`

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda d: nrm(d.xs(d.name)))
```

#### Without the normalization function and moment calculations

```
df.groupby(level=1).pipe(lambda g: df.sub(g.mean(), level=1).div(g.std(), level=1)) \
  .sub(OldRange[0]).mul(np.diff(OldRange)[0]).div(np.diff(NewRange)[0]).add(NewRange[0])
```

---

#### Details

```
mu

          0         1         2         3         4
0 -0.065247 -0.221818 -0.272167 -0.666434  0.353295
1  0.246533  0.049811 -0.279924 -0.025732  0.032529
2 -0.168676 -0.659385 -0.600390  0.211917 -0.007368
3  0.626222  0.072566 -0.702487 -0.338123 -0.009424
4 -0.286499  0.549944 -0.257438 -0.177977  0.254984
```

---

```
sg

          0         1         2         3         4
0  1.307826  1.226733  1.250311  0.931911  0.833170
1  0.758097  0.610464  0.988931  0.780028  0.696543
2  0.679647  0.962712  0.838219  0.530177  1.029039
3  0.774872  0.751137  0.570692  0.743676  0.966374
4  0.935141  0.988090  0.808165  0.937511  1.023745
```

---

```
# Before
dict_of_dfs['df0']

          0         1         2         3         4
0 -2.129724 -1.268466 -1.970500 -2.259055 -0.349286
1 -0.026955  0.316236  0.348782  0.715364  0.770763
2 -0.608208  0.352390 -0.352521 -0.415869 -0.911575
3 -0.142538  0.746839 -1.504157  0.611362  0.400219
4 -0.959443  1.494226 -0.346508 -1.471558  1.063243
```

---

```
# After
dict_of_dfs['df0']

          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.085287  0.128808  0.098500  0.077461  0.129404
1  0.158355  0.206186  0.218145  0.237005  0.243591
2  0.141198  0.243058  0.197743  0.108954  0.127279
3  0.120473  0.233860  0.095716  0.256605  0.205434
4  0.136823  0.237340  0.173387  0.097212  0.227371
```

Comment: I was about to go this exact route :-)

Comment: Nice logic but the final result is not something I'd have expected (most are 99). Are you sure that "mu" is taking the average of all one cell in each dataframe (for example, all cell (3,8) in every 10 dataframe) together?

Comment: I messed up and have fixed it a bit ago.  Refresh the page. @mike.depetriconi

Comment: I've used the "Without the normalization function and moment calculations" method but my terminal is outputting "Killed: 9", or when I run on Spyder it kills my kernel. How can I overcome this?

Comment: @mike.depetriconi dang!  That is beyond my expertise.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: It's version '0.20.3'

Comment: Ahh!  That's why.  the `pipe` method for `groupby` objects was introduced in `0.21` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.pipe.html

Comment: thank you. Also, if I want to use the "Without the normalization function and moment calculations" method only, does it actually update the dict_of_dfs? Because when I run my code it looks like it's not updating it.
Here is my code:
dict_of_dfs = dict(enumerate(tmpListForNormalisation))
dframes = pd.concat(dict_of_dfs)
OldRange = np.array([-3, 3])
NewRange = np.array([0, 100])
dframes.groupby(level=1).pipe(lambda g: dframes.sub(g.mean(), level=1).div(g.std(), level=1)) \
  .sub(OldRange[0]).mul(np.diff(OldRange)[0]).div(np.diff(NewRange)[0]).add(NewRange[0])

Comment: No.  My apologies.  That only produces a larger dataframe with the results.  Just like the example above it.  You could use it to update the dataframes in the list or dictionary, but that example doesn't do that.

Comment: oh ok. Do you think this would update them if I update them like this: for k, d in dict_of_dfs.items():
    if d is None:
        continue
    
    d.loc[:] = dframes.groupby(level=1).pipe(lambda g: dframes.sub(g.mean(), level=1).div(g.std(), level=1)) \
                .sub(OldRange[0]).mul(np.diff(OldRange)[0]).div(np.diff(NewRange)[0]).add(NewRange[0])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193405/discussion-between-mike-depetriconi-and-pirsquared).

Answer (score 0):

I might be off but is this what you're trying to do?

Using a `for` loop, the cell within row `i` and column `c` is extracted from each `df` as `x`, manipulated to give you `val`, then appended to `l`:

```
i = row_value
c = column_name
rangex = []

for df in [df1, df2, ... df10]:
    val = df.loc[i,c]
    rangex.append(val)

for elem in rangex:
    val = (elem - np.mean(rangex))/np.std(rangex)
    val = (((val - (-3.0)) * NewRange) / OldRange) + 0.0
    listrangex.append( val )
```

Comment: thanks for this. Is there no efficient way using pandas dataframes to do all of this? I'm afraid this might take some time to run...

Comment: @mike.depetriconi - how many dataframes are we talking about?  10x dataframes shouldn't be a problem.  If you're looking for something that uses less lines of code, that is another thing :)